# How to define $\pi$ using the least upper bound property and only knowing the perimeter of an $n$-gon

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Is it possible to define $\pi$ with only knowledge of some n-gons perimeter. Everything I find seems to include at least knowledge about the radius of the circle to find a number for pi?

edit: It seems the questions implies that n is known and wants to account for a variety of different shapes

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by this. How can one value let you use the least upper bound property? Also, there are $n$-gons of any possible perimeter, if the radius varies. Please clarify this question.

Comment: You can't determine that with the perimeter, alone, you need additional information (but knowing the perimeter of a regular $n$-gon *and* $n$ would suffice, too).

Comment: So if you knew the perimeter of say a hexagon you would be able to define pi using the least upper bound property even without knowing the radius?

Comment: If I know it's a regular hexagon, and the perimeter is $6$, I *know* the radius ($1$).

Comment: A geometric def'n of $\pi$ could be the least upper bound of the  set of perimeters of  polygons inscribed in a circle of radius $1/2,$  although the restriction to regular polygons  yields the same  lub. .... Any polygon inscribed in a circle of radius $1/2$ has perimeter less than $\pi $....

Comment: "with only knowledge of some n-gons perimeter"  Some? No.  But if we knew *all* n-gon's perimeters we could.  But we don't and can't know that so ...no.

Comment: So... are you asking if the only information we had was that there is a 27-gon with unknown radius and perimeter of 538, can you find the value of pi?  The answer to that is of course not (any polygon can have any perimeter).  However if we know what the radius (or altitude) is, we can find a number close to but less (or more) than pi.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot talk about $\pi$ as ratio between circumference and diameter of a circle without talking about the radius of this circle.

Given a circle of radius $1$ one can compute the circumference $L_{2^n}$ of inscribed regular $2^n$-gons in terms of $n$-times nested square roots.  (That's what Archimedes has done.) Furthermore the triangle inequality shows that the sequence $n\mapsto L_{2^n}$ is increasing. The only special thing about $2^n$ is that we can compute the $L_{2^n}$ explicitly. But it is intuitively obvious that we should define $\pi$ as
$$\pi:={1\over2}\sup_{N\geq3}L_N\ .$$
In order to be sure that this $\pi$ is indeed a real number we have to make sure that the $L_N$ are bounded above. Assume for simplicity that we only consider $N$s of the form $N=4M$. The circumference $L_N$ of the inscribed regular $N$-gon is (by the triangle inequality) smaller than the circumference $U_N$ of the circumscribed regular $N$-gon. This circumscribed $N$-gon is produced by $N$ tangent lines to the circle. We now remove one tangent line after the other, making sure that in the end four tangents making a square remain. Each time the circumference of the changing polygon is increased, and at the end we arrive at the circumference $U_4=8$. It follows that $L_N<U_N<8$ for all $N$.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the radius from what's given, if you assume a regular $n$-gon.

Let's say your $n$-gon is inscribed in a circle. Let's say that you know $n$, and you know the perimeter $P$.

The length of one side of the $n$-gon is $P/n$, and the central angle subtended by the two points of intersection of that side with the circle is $2\pi/n$, (with $n \geq 3$). Let's call these two points of intersection $A$ and $B$, and the center of the circle $C$.

From this, you can calculate the radius of the circle by noting that the radius $R$ is the same as the sides $AC$ and $BC$ of the isosceles triangle $ACB$. Then use law of sines to find the radius:

$$\frac{\sin(2\pi/n)}{P/n} = \frac{\sin[(\pi - 2 \pi/n)/2]}{R}.$$

Comment: He want to define pi, and you use it in your calculations?

Comment: @Ameryr I was thinking the way it would go would be to take the limit of $P/R$ as $n \to \infty$; one should get $2\pi$. But maybe a more basic argument is needed.

Comment: $\sin (2\pi/n)$ doesn't require that the value of $\pi$ being known.  $2\pi$ in this context the "full" angle of a circle.  You may replace it with $360$ degrees and things would be the same.  However we don't have any method of knowing values of sin nor how to take the limit of $n*\sin(360/2n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Start with a circle of radius $1$ and let $C_n$ be the perimeter of your n-gon.

Note that $ (C_n)$ is an increasing sequence which is bounded above by the circumference of the circle.

According to the Monotone Convergence Theorem, your sequence converges to its supremum which is the perimeter of the circle.

The radius of our circle is $1$ so the circumference is $2\pi $ .

Thus $ \pi $ could be defined as half of the supremum of $(C_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

The radius is irrelevant.  The perimeter, sides, altitudes etc. of the $n$-gon will be linearly proportional to the radius so we may assume the radius is $1$ unit.

If we take an inscribed $n$-gon, and if the base of the $n$-gon with radius $1$ is $b_n$ then the perimeter of the $n$-gon is $b_n*n$ and if $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n*n$ exist that would be the value of $2\pi$.

The problem is, we have no formula for calculating $b_n$ nor $\lim b_n*n$.  If we assume trig functions are well defined then we know $b_n = 2\sin {\frac {360}{2n}}$ (Cut the $n$-gon into $n$ isoceles triangles and cut those into two right triangles-- the hypotenuse is $1$; the principal angle is $\frac {360}{2n}$; and the opposite leg is $\frac 12 b_n = \sin \frac {360}{2n}$) .  But we have no algebraic way of calculating that. Nor how to calculate $\pi = \lim_{n\to \infty} n*\sin{\frac {360}{2n}}$.

We'd have no choice but to actually *construct* these n-gons and physically measure the lengths (which presumably *was* done in ancient times).

Alternatively we could inscribe a circle inside the $n$-gon.  The the adjacent side of the right triangles of the the $n$-gon is the radius.  The opposite side is $\frac 12 b_n$, so $\tan \frac {360}{2n} = \frac {\frac 12 b_n}{1}$ so $b_n = 2\tan \frac{360}{2n}$ and $\pi = \lim_{n\to \infty} n*\tan\frac{360}{2n}$

But we have no way of calculating those values.

And we are making two assumption in assuming i) those limits converge and 2) trigonometric functions are consistent.  As the first limit is increasing and bounded above (and the second decreasing and bounded below) and as Euclids fifth postulate allows that similar triangles are similar these assumptions are valid.

But we are really doing things backwards using modern results (limits and trigonometry).